# Orchard CMS & ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am starting a new project that requires extensive CMS functionality. I would also like it to be a full MVC 4 site.

I just installed Orchard CMS from the Web Platform Installer for the first time - and loading the solution (after web setup) - there are no Views / Models or Controllers folder.

I have read that Orchard is based on this technology - what is the best way to get started fully customising the HTML / CSS - and adding my own models / views etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Orchard is based on MVC, but it's also modular. Modules add features to the core but are essentially decoupled from one another, as much as possible. They are also built on ASP.NET MVC Areas. You will find those modules and themes (and also their views, controllers and models) inside of the subfolders of the /Modules and /Themes directories. Those directories themselves can be found right under the root of the web site (src/Orchard.Web if you are using a source code drop). Finally, the core modules can be found under Core, with a similar structure.

Comment: Thanks - how should I approach applying my design to a new project?

Comment: That's pretty broad--there's some documentation on writing a new theme here http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme that will probably point you in the right direction

Comment: I think the initial question was answered. How about granting the answer? We'll be happy to answer any additional specific questions you may have as separate questions.